# Programmer slang expression for "We'll cross the bridge when we get there"

Tags: idioms, popular-refrains, software

What is the software industry word/term/phrase for the saying "We'll cross the bridge when we will get there"?

I need to refer to a feature that can be deferred until its time comes.

For example, *YAGNI* ("You ain't gonna need it") is used for software features that won't be used, so they would be redundant to code — i.e. don't over-develop a feature.

Similarly, what will be a term for the feature in question? An acronym would be great, but *WCBWGT* doesn't quite cut it.

**Update (adding example to provide more context)**

The part 'not wasting any human resource' fits the bill for YAGNI. The context I meant was 'not wasting ... "yet" '

For example: Suppose your objective is to build an autonomous car that can do navigation (sprint 1), speech recognition (sprint 2), image analysis for road bumps (sprint 3) etc During design discussion in sprint 1, if someone wants to resolve or talk for resolution of cameras for image analysis - because that is clearly sprint 3, you would want to tell her "we will cross that bridge when we get there"

Comment: It is normally just called a *placeholder*.

Comment: "Vaporwear" is a common term, though not with precisely the above meaning.

Comment: @Chenmunka : _placeholder_ does not carry the connotation of **deferring**. The word instead should mean "something that is not to be touched until its time comes."

@ Hot Licks : I could not find "vaporwear" meaning on Internet, can you please explain it a bit more and perhaps cite some source too

Comment: Really. You couldn't find [the Merriam-Webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vaporware). Or [the AHD definition](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=vaporware). Or [the Wiktionary definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vaporware). Or [the Oxford Dictionaries definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/vaporware).  Or [the Dictionary.com definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vaporware). Or [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaporware). What version of the Internet are you using? You need Web 2.0 or higher.

Comment: Thanks for being rude @RegDwigнt . I never knew vapor"wear" and vapor"ware" were synonyms. I use the internet printed out on sheets from quite a while ago, sorry. Leaving this aside, vaporware seems to be close to what I am looking for albeit it has "advertise" thingy in it - still upvoting @ Hot Licks

Comment: @HotLicks I would like to accept your answer vaporware for the meanwhile, your choice to convert it to a answer from a comment. I couldn't even upvote your comment for some reason...

Comment: Could you give a more concrete example of what you are asking for? Some well known case from the industry would be perfect. Depending on the context, not wasting any human resources on a feature that no one would probably ever need may be either wise management or utter lack of foresight.

Comment: The serious version of that saying is "We'll fall off that bridge when we come to it. "

Answer (score 1):

If its a defect in the Software after release, it is termed a "Feature". If it is missing from the Software in the first place, its a "Planned Milestone Feature"

Answer (score 0):

Update: I came across the term ***implementation detail*** and [one if its interpretations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1777729/2361131) - *a design decision but not a concrete implementation* - seems quite close to the context (perhaps like a delegated placeholder but not exactly a stub). 
Though, the nuance is "it can be **implemented** in different ways" instead of "it will not be implemented until its significance comes into foreground" (I guess ***deferred detail*** cuts it ...)

---

Maybe [Lazy Loading][2]

> Lazy loading is a design pattern commonly used in computer programming
> to defer initialization of an object until the point at which it is
> needed.

Edit: After undercat's comment below, I realize I was **not** looking for Lazy loading - as that would mean the feature was coded even if not used(loaded) yet.

P.S: I am wondering now if "Lazy Coding" would be acceptable to the ears instead - neologism would work if it doesn't hurt

Comment: In your question, did you mean deferring the implementation of a feature (thus saving human resources), or deferring the loading of said feature into computer memory (thus saving RAM and CPU)? Lazy loading only applies to the latter. If a feature was not implemented because no customer has asked for it, that is NOT lazy loading.

Comment: @undercat: I see the light in your point. I have marked my answer "unaccepted" again :(

Answer (score 0):

[Project Planning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_planning) is where one partitions the system into the bits that are needed and in which order, so that's really the industry term for it.

(of course, "We'll cross that bridge when we come to it." or "Let's not borrow trouble." are often used when discussing such planning in *my* experience.)

Comment: "Let's not borrow trouble" is a good expression (new one for me atleast) but it gives the 'future' feature a 'problematic' connotation.
    Sure coding it right now will thus be problematic to current project planning but that is an 'implication' and not the 'action'
    Project Planning, however, is a very broad-spectrum antibiotic though I am just looking for a thermometer :) I might as well rephrase what I intend to articulate about the feature - "this feature is not important as of now so we will code it when its time comes".